# How to remove domain from paginate.nextUrl?

Tags: server, pagination

What makes a site's domain appear within the output of `paginate.nextUrl`? I am experiencing a situation where it is not there in my local dev environment, but IS there on production server. I'm sure it's related to some more global configuration, but the answer is so far not obvious. Thanks!